# Monte Carlo pseudocode by Richard S. Sutton and Andrew G. Barto

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I'm a reading a book, "Reinforcement Learning" by S. Sutton and Andrew G. Barto

Sutton's Book explains:
"For Monte Carlo policy iteration it is natural to alternate between evaluation and improvement on an episode-by-episode basis. After each episode, the observed returns are used for policy evaluation, and then the policy is improved at all the states visited in the episode. A complete simple algorithm along these lines, which we call Monte Carlo ES, for Monte Carlo with Exploring Starts, is given in pseudo code in the box on the next page"

[image: Text]

However, in this pseudo code, it seems last two lines, which correspond to policy evaluation and policy improvement are done for each step of episode. According to Sutton's explanation, should't last two lines be moved 2 indentations to left so that policy evaluation and policy improvement are performed for each episode?

Comment: Please note that https://ai.stackexchange.com/ is full of people who have read Sutton&Barto and they don't bite :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar confusion but already with the first pseudocode describing monte-carlo in this book. As far as I understood by now: Actually all steps under the "unless" clause are meant to be executed for all states in the list (starting from the end-state and going back to start-state) UNLESS they didn't alredy apear in the list up to now (the currently regarded state St)

Thus the identation would be correct, both quality-function and policy are updated for every state that was visited in the episode (but only once if it was visited multiple times during that episode). If you look at it that's just what they've written in the explaining text you cited above.

Remember (that was confusing me too): The state named "St" in the code is not the start-state but just the currently regarded intermediate state at time t